# Windows XP not assigning drive letter to Western Digital Passport

Tags: windows-xp

I have got a Western Digital Passport to do a backup of my files, but the drive is not showing under My Computer.

It is showing up in disk management as a `healthy(GPT protective partion)` but has no drive letter.

Upon right-clicking it all the options are grayed out.

Things i have tried:

- uninstalling the drivers.
- manually assigning a drive letter through command prompt.
- formating the drive using another machine.

[image: disk management]

Comment: A screenshot of Disk Management is required in order to answer your question.

Comment: why are you still using Windows XP these days? Exposing it to the internet is not only dangerous for you but also for others

Comment: Are you sure Win XP knows what to do with a GPT drive?

Comment: https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/access-gpt-protective-partition-without-losing-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP (32-bit) cannot read GPT partitioned disks.

From [Windows and GPT FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-and-gpt-faq):

> #### Can the 32-bit version of Windows XP read, write, and boot from GPT disks?
>
> No. The 32-bit version will see only the Protective MBR. The EE partition will not be mounted or otherwise exposed to application software.

You will need to convert the disk to MBR in order to be able to see it or use it. You should be able to right click the area showing "Disk 1" and see an option to convert to MBR.

**If you have any data you wish to keep on the disk then you should back it up first.**

Most disk management softwares should be able to convert the disk for you. If you cannot do it using the built in disk manager then Acronis or another tool should do it.